# Failing to compile C using GCC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, c, arm

I am trying to compile test.c as described [this](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/WiringNP:_NanoPi_NEO/NEO2/Air_GPIO_Programming_with_C) NanoPi Neo guide. However, when ever I try to run the gcc command to compile, I get this error message...

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
  Supported emulations:
   armelf_linux_eabi
   armelfb_linux_eabi
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

...the command...

```
sudo gcc -Wall -o test.c -lwiringPi -lpthread -Wl,-V
```

...and the code I'm trying to compile...

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
int main(void)
{
  wiringPiSetup() ;
  pinMode (7, OUTPUT) ;
  for(;;)
  {
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH) ;
    delay (500) ;
    digitalWrite(7,  LOW) ;
    delay (500) ;
  }
}
```

May I guess that this is a possible linking issue? I'm just not sure and I really do know how to change it.
I am rather novice-like when it comes to topics like C, Linux and the like. :)

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Superuser!  Are you sure you want to use sudo? And,  you sure that you shouldn't also include some of these?  <stdio.h> <stdlib.h> <stdint.h> (Point out any errors I make in my comment! If someone spotting anything!)

Comment: Why would you use `sudo` for this? You are creating a file you can't modify yourself.

Comment: The `-o` option designates the **output** file. So you got lucky if the compiler didn't trash test.c. The correct command is `gcc -Wall test.c -o myprogram` followed by the options you have in your command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not specified any `.c` source files since the `-o` specifies the output as @user3386109 mentioned.

```
sudo gcc -Wall test.c -o output_file_name -lwiringPi -lpthread -Wl,-V
```